# Laravel raw query parameters for IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've using Laravel `DB::select()` for raw query, facing issue while passing parameters to `IN` clause.

**1st Query:**

```
$team = DB::table('TeamUserLinks')
             ->orderBy('User_Name', 'asc')
             ->lists('User_Name');
```

**2nd Query:**

```
$user_tasks = DB::select("SELECT usr_first_name,usr_last_name,username,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_assignee_user t WHERE t.user_id = u.id AND t.task_status = 1) as status_open,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_assignee_user t WHERE t.user_id = u.id AND t.task_status = 1 AND t.task_due_date < CURRENT_DATE) as overdue, 
    FROM user u where usr_initials in(" . $team . ")");
```

**Also tried:**

```
"FROM user u where usr_initials in(?)",array($team));
```

and

```
$team = implode($team) //Not working while passing after implode
```

and

```
usr_initials in('" . $team . "')");//Not working with quotes
```

2nd query always return empty result.

Comment: What is the value of `$team`?

Comment: I think your query could be rewritten more simply using conditional aggregation by user.

Comment: It's an array of strings

Comment: If it is array of strings - use `implode`

Comment: @u_mulder same result with implode

Comment: Did you add quotes?

Comment: Yes ,tried with quotes but not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct query using `in ()` with strings is:

```
WHERE field IN ('String1', 'String2', 'String3')
```

So you need to add both **quotes** and **commas**.

In a simple way it is:

```
 "... FROM user u where usr_initials in('" . implode("', ' ", $team . "')");
```

But, when you meet `'` as a part of name - your query will be broken, so it is better to use prepared statements. Something like this should work:

```
// here we create array of `?` of a size of team.
$marks = array_fill(0, sizeof($team), '?');
// imploding it later will give us a string `?, ?, ?`
// later every `?` will be replaced with a value of `$team`

$user_tasks = DB::select(
    "SELECT usr_first_name,usr_last_name,username,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_assignee_user t WHERE t.user_id = u.id AND t.task_status = 1) as status_open,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_assignee_user t WHERE t.user_id = u.id AND t.task_status = 1 AND t.task_due_date < CURRENT_DATE) as overdue, 
        FROM user u where usr_initials in(" . implode(',', $marks) . ")", 
    $team
);
```

Comment: Thanks , Its very help full

Comment: Huge help! Thanks!